# What is the development process like at Google?

Tags: development-process

What tools do they use? What processes? What rules do they have regarding code? How do they test their code?

Comment: One thing I do know is that they publicly release their [style guides](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the practices of a single company. This is not something that the general programming community can be expected to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was searching a couple of weeks ago for some info about google development methodologies and found the following which I [posted on my blog](http://www.chrisdoesdev.com/?tag=methodologies)

- Steve Y - Good Agile vs Bad Agile
- A summary of google methodologies from Steve Y's post
- Google Product Development/Management Process

I can't post more than one link at the moment, though, (stackexchange spam prevention apparently), so follow the link to my blog or google the above strings.

Chris.